# Can anyone get access to my PHP source code?

Tags: php, encryption

Is it possible to hide the .php file on the server...?

I have a website which sometimes calls php files inside iframes, now I wouldn't like it if somebody copied that code, so how would I hide it?
Or do I have to encrypt it?

Speed is a huge matter in my case, so anything that doesn't affect performance is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

With a correctly configured web server, the PHP code isn't visible to your website visitors.  For the PHP code to be accessible by people who visit your website, the server would have to be configured to display it as text instead of processing it as PHP code.

So, in other words, if you visit your website and you see a HTML page and not PHP code, your server is working correctly and no one can get to the PHP code.

Comment: -IF- php is installed correct, and there isn't an issue with php short tags in use, and of course if we're not talking about a user with access to the web server itself.

Answer (score 1):

Which code? Your PHP source code? The only code a user see is your html code, PHP is processed on the server side!

Comment: Okay, so they cant in any way get access to it? or somehow download it?

Comment: There's no way they can download your PHP source code. When a `.php` file is requested by a browser, the code in that `.php` file is executed, not displayed.

Comment: They can download it, but just via ftp, if the web-server (apache?) is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

If your php-files are parsed by the http server, nobody can get them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still paranoid after the assurances provided here, you can make your code much more difficult for someone else to read by "obfuscating" it ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code)).

If you Google "php obfuscator", you'll find tons of PHP obfuscator products, many of them free.

Some examples:
[PHP Obfuscator](http://www.raizlabs.com/software/phpobfuscator/)

[Code Eclipse](http://www.codeeclipse.com/)

[Professional PHP Obfuscator/Encoder](http://www.obfusc.com/)

Obfuscation does not affect performance. Only readability for humans.

Answer (score 0):

If someone access a php file on your site all they will see is the code output by the PHP script (e.g. any HTML, or Javascript) - they won't see the source for the PHP page itself (and will have no way to access it).

If you are concerned about them seeing the output (e.g. the HTML the PHP script generates) from a practical point of view, there isn't anything you can do about that (the most you can do is obfuscate it, but that is largely pointless).

Answer (score 0):

> I have a website which sometimes calls
>   php files inside iframes, now I
>   wouldn't like it if somebody copied
>   that code, so how would I hide it? Or
>   do I have to encrypt it?

No, that makes no sense and would not work. You have to realize that the PHP code is executed on your server to serve a HTTP request, and that the iframe results in a separate HTTP request from the main page.

If you want to prevent others from including the iframe in their own page, you could [check the referrer](http://www.trap17.com/index.php/Check-Referrer-Prevent-Linking-Sites_t40295.html) header and have the iframe page show an error if the referrer is not from your site, but that could cause problems for some legimitate users and can also be circumvented.

Alternative solution: do not use iframes; instead, integrate the PHP code that currently displays the iframe's content in your main page. This will work for all users and cannot be circumvented.

Of course, you still can't prevent others from requesting your page, extracting the content from the HTML and displaying it on their page - that's just how the internet works.

Answer (score 0):

Put your important files like passwords login etc into a folder outside the web folder. E.g. under C:  you can set this include path in php ini file.  Then you are pretty safe.  Definitely you should store your mysql access code outside the htdocs folders.   I think The php code is "includes". So check yourself.  Good luck

Comment: Actually this is a good hint and adds a 2nd security layer for the case that some configuration changes of the server turn out to be insecure and wrong.

Comment: One issue could be that for the server public FTP is (still) configured where sensitive information is available, i.e. php files with passwords for phpMyAdmin or similar. This won't be remarked as long as the files are only called by http(s).
Even if some browsers never support the ftp protocol any longer, those files could be retrived with cUrl or wget.

Comment: Furthermore, even if the files can't be stored outside of the web-directory, the public read access should be removed. Then the server should be able to read them nevertheless, while the public can't, even in text-mode.