# PHPMailer and real email's username and password

Tags: php, email, security

I'm using PHPMailer atm and I'm kinda suspicions about how it stores username and password of the mail:

```
$mail->Username = 'username@gmail.com'; // example
$mail->Password = 'qwertypassword'; // example
```

This seems very vulnerable. I'm storing this information in my root folder ('public_html'). Perhaps I should move it outside of it, for more security reasons? What are my options if I don't want to use my password like that in the file - is there any kind of workarounds for this?

Perhaps to move it for another mail, say the server's one and only then to send it to gmail - would that be more secure?

Comment: Well read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1873808/6140684) . It will be vulnerable only if someone gets access to your server.

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos yes, I know. I'm using shared hosting and for obvious reasons can't trust it much